# How to create a sloped pocket?

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-printing

I want to create a sloped pocket for a rectangular cube 14 inches by 11 inches and 1 inch in thickness.

The sloped pocket would be 12 inches by 9 inches and tapers the top surface from zero down to 1/2 inches at the bottom.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: hello, could you please share a reference image?

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you know what you want to achieve, and words alone make it hard to visualize what your goal is. Describe the issue in detail, add reference [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) of the desired result with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 Cubes: One as the wood piece, the other one as the *Cutter* object. Scale them to the desired proportions. Move and rotate the Cutter, so it sticks half-way in the wood and give it a *Bevel* modifier (with maybe 10 segments) to round the corners:

[image]

Give the wood a *Boolean* modifier (*Mode: Difference*, *Object: Cutter*, Solver: Fast) and hide the *Cutter* object in the *Outliner*:

[image]